# Querying dbconnect returns shifted time results (incorrect time zone)

Tags: r, rodbc, r-dbi, dbplyr

I am interfacing MySQL database on remote server using `DBI::dbconnect()` function.

When querying for results based on filtering datetime column, the server returns correct results, but they are shifted by +1 hour (fe. 21:00:00 instead of 20:00:00). Both R time zone and server time zone are in `CET` (+01:00). But the connection acts as if the server time zone was `UTC` intead. See:

```
q = dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT NOW(), @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;")
dbFetch(q)
                NOW() @@global.time_zone @@session.time_zone
1 2020-02-21 12:47:56             SYSTEM              +00:00

Sys.time() #System time for R machine
[1] "2020-02-21 12:48:10 CET"
```

I have tried to set both `timezone` and `timezone_out` arguments of `dbconnect()` to `CET` but it does not change the query results.

I don't know how else to deal with it apart from substracting an hour from the results after fetching the data to R.

Comment: Just guessing here. but could it be that one observes daylightsavings and the other does not?

Comment: It selects the correct rows in the database, but upon displaying/colleting them it adds the +1h. I just think that `timezone` and `timezone_out` arguments don't do a thing, because changing them returns the same result with same +1h problem.

Comment: The best working work-around I found is to `filter` the data in DB, `mutate` it to `as.character`, `collect()`  from database and `mutate` back to date(time) object. It is ridiculous but probably the least error prone solution.